# HTTPS block images phpbb3

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, phpbb3

I've added a SSL certificate and I've noticed that some images are blocked by the HTTPS.
For example on index I can see all the images but for some reasons on the login page it doesn't show the image.
http://prntscr.com/dnl3jc

But on index it shows the background (the background from the index is the same as the background from the login page)
http://prntscr.com/dnl3qc

That is what I use for HTTPS redirect in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Later edit: I've noticed that only the Register and Login page have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in order for everything to be displayed properly in HTTPS:// every link that's not localy, it doesn't matter if image/symbol etc has to be a HTTPS:// link not a HTTP:// .